# Neural network basics multiply

Tags: java, neural-network, encog, biological-neural-network

Hello i am learning neural network.
is a neuron storing only a value between 1 or -1 ? i cant give value 255 or 1024 like ?
i was looking for encog java library XOR function solver example.
I wanted to change XOR to Multiplier by changing XOR_INPUT and XOR_IDEAL.

Here is source location:
http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Hello_World

I have changed

FROM:

```
/**
 * The input necessary for XOR.
 */
public static double XOR_INPUT[][] = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 1.0, 0.0 },
        { 0.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 } };

/**
 * The ideal data necessary for XOR.
 */
public static double XOR_IDEAL[][] = { { 0.0 }, { 1.0 }, { 1.0 }, { 0.0 } };
```

TO:

```
/**
 * The input necessary for XOR.
 */
public static double XOR_INPUT[][] = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 1.0, 0.0 },
        { 1.0, 2.0 }, { 2.0, 4.0 } };

/**
 * The ideal data necessary for XOR.
 */
public static double XOR_IDEAL[][] = { { 0.0 }, { 1.0 }, { 2.0 }, { 8.0 } };
```

After changing value to these.
I got infinite loop and outputs constant:

Epoch #274107 Error:12.75

Epoch #274108 Error:12.75

Epoch #274109 Error:12.75

Epoch #274110 Error:12.75

Epoch #274111 Error:12.75

Epoch #274112 Error:12.75

Epoch #274113 Error:12.75

Epoch #274114 Error:12.75

Epoch #274115 Error:12.75

Epoch #274116 Error:12.75

Epoch #274117 Error:12.75

Epoch #274118 Error:12.75

Epoch #274119 Error:12.75

Here is the questions;

1-)is this called local minima?

2-) do i need to set value between (0 and 1) or (-1 and 1) is a must?

3-) how can i solve simple multiplication solver problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to do as follows: (a) Add another hidden layer. (b) normalize your data. I haven't messed around neural network recently but if memory serves they tend to work best when the input ranges between 0 and 1.

Comment: adding more hidden layers (than one) is **almost always** a bad idea (in simple neural networks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output layer is sigmoid, which means it can **only** represent values between 0 and 1, so it is impossible to train such a network to recognize anything else. However, it is not the network falw, you should scale your output so it fits into this interval, and later on descale.

Simply:

- current outputs 0,1,2,8
- we assume, that 8 is the "maximum" value, and scale them down by 8 getting: 0,1/8,1/4,1

Now you train your network, and to retrieve original outputs simply multiply the value by 8.

Remember, that simple neural networks are **not** tools for symbolic computations. If you are looking for a model which will actually find the `a*b` formula then read about `symbolic function networks`.